# Modelo Roofline

Tags: desempenho, gpgpu

Tenho um TPC para um disciplina da faculdade (disciplina de Arquitectura Avançada de Computadores), em que me é colocada uma questão para obter o desempenho máximo atingível em GFLOP/s. Após alguma pesquisa intensiva, cheguei à conclusão que este valor se obtém através do mínimo entre dois valores, em relação às caraterísticas do sistema:

- Desempenho máximo, que neste caso é 34 GFLOP/s e;
- A largura de banda máxima da memória, que é 25 GB/s.

E ainda:

- A intensidade aritmética que é de 1 FLOP/s.

A fórmula do desempenho máximo atingível é:

> Mínimo entre desempenho máximo (34 GFLOP/s) e largura de banda máxima de memória (25 GB/s) * intensidade aritmética (1 FLOP/s).

Não consigo obter o resultado porque não consigo encontrar a relação entre GB/s e FLOP/s.

Dado um gráfico pelo stor, existe uma relação entre intensidade aritmética e GFLOP/s.

Sendo que para intensidade aritmética (I.A.) = 1, então y = 16 GFLOP/s.

Portanto, seria 25 GB/s * 16 GFLOP/s. Mesmo assim, não há conversão entre estes dois valores.

Existe também no gráfico uma referência à largura de banda máxima de memória, mas não consigo arranjar a relação. Sei que há um pico, não sei se o gráfico é igual para todos os exercícios.

Comment: Oi, editei a sua pergunta porque o português estava tão ruim que eu nem conseguia entender o que você estava tentando dizer, desculpe-me a sinceridade. Acho que agora está melhor, mas dê uma revisada para se certificar que não baguncei com algo durante a edição. Além disso, o que é "stor"?

Comment: Você pode postar o enunciado completo do exercício? Acho que há alguma coisa errada ou no enunciado ou na sua forma de se chegar a essa fórmula. Lembrando que "Intensidade Aritmética é definida com o número de operações realizadas por palavra de memória transferida." e que FLOP/s é "operações de ponto flutuante por segundo". Ou seja são unidades de medidas referentes a quantidade de trabalho realizada em relação ao tempo, enquanto que GB/s é quantidade de dados trafegados em relação ao tempo - ou seja, são medidas de natureza diferentes.